# What statistical data/quantities are known about the time spent by a generic orbit of an ergodic system in a fixed set?

Tags: pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

By the ergodic theorem, we know that for almost every point, the average time spent by an orbit in a set is equal to the relative measure of that set.

What other information about that time can we infer from this setting without assuming more about the system? E.g. average rate at which the orbit returns to the set, the average length of each visit, ... Can we know anything about them?

Comment: I believe the answer is you can say almost nothing beyond the averages (see Kac's theorem for results of the average return time: if you're in the set, how long do you have to wait to come back?) without knowing more about the system. The key word is "return time statistics" and there is a fairly substantial volume of work on issues around this.